# Rotate object to face in the direction of movement

Tags: c++, rotation, game-development

I'm working on a simple game where I have a plane in the sky and I am giving it a circular path around some circle with a radius. The plane spawns facing positive z and when moving around this circle it just stays facing positive z and never turns to face the direction of it's movement around the circle.

I've tried calculating a new direction but this doesn't seem to be working and I'm quite confused about this.

Quite new to making games so apologies if this is a simple question.

```
    void Update(float deltaTime, const Matrix& worldMatrix, const Matrix& viewMatrix)
    {

        float x = radius * cos(angle);
        float y = radius * sin(angle);

        position = vec3(position.x + x, position.y, position.z + y);

        angle += speed * dt;

        if(angle > 2 * M_PI)
        {
            angle -= 2 * M_PI;
        }

        vec3 direction;
        direction.x = std::cos(rad(yaw)) * std::cos(rad(pitch));
        direction.y = std::sin(rad(pitch));
        direction.z = std::sin(rad(yaw)) * std::cos(rad(pitch));
        direction = direction.unit();

        modelMatrix = viewMatrix * 
        Matrix::Translate(position + direction) * 
        worldMatrix *
        Matrix::Scale(vec3(scale, scale, scale));
    }
```

I've also tried doing:
`auto d = atan2(x, y) * 180 / 3.14;`

but this made the object rotate 360 degrees constantly while moving around the circle instead of being in a fixed focus direction.

Comment: You're updating the plane's position and model matrix, but you're also modifying the direction vector, which is not necessary in this case. To keep the plane oriented in the positive z direction, you can construct the model matrix without changing the plane's direction.

Comment: @CemPolat Thanks for the reply! I'm trying to get the forward direction of the plane to change as it goes around in the circular motion. Currently it starts off facing +Z and then never changes which looks odd when it's turning around the circular motion but the forward direction is never changed

Comment: In that case, you should calculate the forward direction based on its position relative to the center of the circle.

Comment: @CemPolat Thanks for the reply! How might I go about doing that

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the direction vector based on the difference between the plane's current position and the center of the circle to calculate the forward direction of the plane as it moves around the circular path.

Assuming that the center of the circle is at the origin (0, 0, 0), you can calculate the forward direction like this:

```
vec3 center(0, 0, 0); // Assuming the center of the circle is at the origin

// Calculate the direction vector from the plane's current position to the center of the circle
vec3 direction = center - position;
direction = direction.unit(); // Normalize the direction vector

// Now, you can use this direction vector to update your model matrix
modelMatrix = viewMatrix * 
    Matrix::Translate(position + direction) * 
    worldMatrix *
    Matrix::Scale(vec3(scale, scale, scale));
```

Comment: I gave this a go and it circles around as it did before but it remains facing +Z at all times and does not turn to face the direction the curve is going on the circle to make it seem like it's going around it.